# Cloud Sql Instance restart hanging for hours

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

My cloud sql instance became unresponsive today (unable to connect using my normal credentials via mysql-client or the google cloud console) so I decided to restart it to see if that would help, since I couldn't find any better debug suggestions. That was over two hours ago and the db still shows as restarting in my cloud sql dashboard. Others that had this issue were told to email cloud-sql@google.com but it's been over an hour already with no response. I wonder if trying to kill the instance via google's api would clear things up but don't want to screw myself even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this still happening? Would you send an email to cloud-sql@google.com with the link of this stackoverflow post and your instance name? Thank you.

Comment: I actually found other posts that suggested the same thing and, after doing so, was told that 1) that it's not a support address and I shouldn't expect to get a fast response and, more importantly, 2) that this was due to a bug that was triggered after my app engine trial expired. When I upgraded, it apparently got stuck in the suspended state and needed to be manually kicked. The bug has been fixed and is being QA'd so hopefully this doesn't happen to others.  For reference: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/support